# Exception thrown when user attempts to create an appointment in a shared calendar

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

We have an In-house executable which creates Outlook Meetings and Appointments in shared calendars.

One user is having a problem creating appointments in a shared calendar using this code. This code's been running fine for years now.

**WHAT HAS BEEN TRIED:**
I had the user access the Calendar directly through Outlook.  She was able to create meetings in the Shared Calendar without a problem.

**EXCEPTION THROWN:**
"*The operation failed because of a registry or installation problem. Restart Outlook and try again. If the problem persists, reinstall.*"

Re-installing Outlook would be a major inconvenience for the user.

I'm wondering.

1. What area in the Registry would I look at?
2. Would recreating the .PST file be a reasonable alternative?
3. Can I use Outlook Redemption to troubleshoot the user's account?

Comment: What is your code that opens the target folder and creates the appointment?

Comment: I found the answer, and your instinct was right about looking at the code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your Outlook profile (or Outlook installation itself) is corrupted. You can take a look at the Windows event log what else Outlook states about the error incident. At this stage, it is not clear whether it is related to the profile corruption (to re-create a pst) or Outlook itself.

Redemption is a wrapper around Extended MAPI (a low-level API on which Outlook is built on). But it doesn't provide any self-diagnostic services, only convenient access to the low-level functions. However, you can use Redemption for getting your job done without Outlook involved.

I'd suggest opening a support case with Microsoft if you need to continue working with OOM.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it was a data issue.

I asked the user to create Appointments for other shared calendars using our custom executable.  She was able to do so without a problem.

The exception message that I posted came from the call to **GetSharedDefaultFolder**

The *Recipient* parameter was created using an email address that doesn't exist on our Exchange server.   That bad email address came from our database.